# How to update text inside of a div that contains another element?

Tags: javascript, html

If I have this

```
<div>
    foo bar
    <span>blah blah blah</span>
</div>
```

How can I make it into this

```
<div>
    hello world
    <span>blah blah blah</span>
</div>
```

normally in javascript I could just do `.innerText` but if there is another element, how can I not affect that element? Also to ensure that nothing about the span gets changed, including any listeners, etc...

Note: I am looking for a vanilla JS solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you know the structure of the container div and the text is in first textnode you can target the first childNode of the container element

```js
document.querySelector('div').childNodes[0].textContent ='Test '
```

```css
span{ color: red}
```

```html
<div>
    foo bar
    <span>blah blah blah</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit similar to @charlietfl answer.

```js
divA = document.getElementById("divA");
var newText = divA.childNodes[0];
newText.nodeValue = 'new foo bar ';
```

```html
<div id='divA'>
    foo bar
    <span>blah blah blah</span>
    <span>blah blah blah</span>
</div>
```

Comment: whats the difference between nodeValue and textContent?

Answer (score 0):

#### Better:

Access the parent element’s childNodes, and either A) set the first textNode’s textContent or B) remove the existing text node and create/insert its replacement.

#### Easier:

Get the parent’s innerHTML and do a string replacement on “foo bar”. This option is slightly easier to implement but **far more likely to have unintended consequences**. As charlietfl points out in a comment below, it could wipe out event listeners registered on the element’s children.

Comment: Caveat for easier being it would affect event listeners assigned directly to other elements in the container